# Is the result of the which() function *always* ordered?

Tags: r

I want to assure that the result of `which(..., arr.ind = TRUE)` is always ordered, specifically: arranged ascending by `(col, row)`. I do not see such a remark in the `which` function documentation, whereas it *seems* to be the case based on some experiments I made. How I can check / learn if it is the case?

Example. When I run the code below, the output is a matrix in which the results are arranged ascending by `(col, row)` columns.

```
> set.seed(1)
> vals <- rnorm(10)
> valsall <- sample(as.numeric(replicate(10, vals)))
> mat <- matrix(valsall, 10, 10)
> which(mat == max(mat), arr.ind = TRUE)
      row col
 [1,]   1   1
 [2,]   3   1
 [3,]   1   2
 [4,]   2   2
 [5,]  10   2
 [6,]   1   6
 [7,]   2   8
 [8,]   4   8
 [9,]   1   9
[10,]   6   9
```

Comment: Not sure what you need

Comment: I want to learn if function always returns the result in an ordered way.

Comment: Why not just `order` it after the above result ?

Answer (score 1):

**Part1:**

Answering a part of your question on how to understand functions on a deeper level, if the documentation is not enough, without going into the detail of function which().

As match() is not a primitive function (which are written in C), i.e. written using the basic building blocks of R, we can check what's going on behind the scenes by printing the function itself. Note that using the backticks allows to check functions that have reserved names, e.g. +, and is therefore optional in this example. This dense R code can be extremely tiresome to read, but I've found it very educational and it does solve some mental knots every once in a while.

```
> print(`which`)
function (x, arr.ind = FALSE, useNames = TRUE) 
{
    wh <- .Internal(which(x))
    if (arr.ind && !is.null(d <- dim(x))) 
        arrayInd(wh, d, dimnames(x), useNames = useNames)
    else wh
}
<bytecode: 0x00000000058673e0>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

**Part2:**

So after giving up on trying to understand the which and arrayInd function in the way described above, I'm trying it with common sense. The most efficient way to check each value of a matrix/array that makes sense to me, is to at some point convert it to a one-dimensional object. Coercion from matrix to atomic vector, or any reduction of dimensions will always result in concatenating the complete columns of each dimension, so to me it is natural that higher-level functions will also follow this fundamental rule.

```
> testmat <- matrix(1:10, nrow = 2, ncol = 5)
> testmat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10
> as.numeric(testmat)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

I found Hadley Wickham's Advanced R an extremely valuable resource in answering your question, especially the chapters about functions and data structures.
[http://adv-r.had.co.nz/][1]